# Kivy, using functions and getting random info to textinput and random image?

Tags: python, function, random, kivy, textinput

I think I am lost for solution. I didn't get how works the function with .kv pages. 
My  sample codes are below. Problem is when I clicked to "Good Luck" button I get an error such as "AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'app'" I tried replace my function lines to different places such as under class but keep get different errors, Am I missing something obvious or just my whole way is wrong?

main.py

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from trakt.users import User
import random
import imdb
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
import kivy.app
kivy.require('1.9.1')

moviesDB = imdb.IMDb()
myuser = User(str('lunedor'))
watchlist = myuser.watchlist_movies

def dataget():
    global myline
    myline = str(random.choice(watchlist))[9:1000]
    movies = moviesDB.search_movie(str(myline))
    id = movies[0].getID()
    global movie
    movie = moviesDB.get_movie(id)
    global posterurl
    posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]
    global title
    title = movie['title']
    global year
    year = movie["year"]
    global rating
    rating = movie["rating"]
    global runtime
    runtimes = movie["runtimes"]
    runtime = ' '.join(map(str, runtimes))
    global directStr
    directors = movie["directors"]
    directStr = ' '.join(map(str, directors))
    global writerStr
    writers = movie["writers"]
    writerStr = ', '.join(map(str, writers))
    global casting
    casting = movie["cast"]
    global actors
    actors = ', '.join(map(str, casting))
    global summary
    summary = movie["plot outline"]
    genres = movie["genres"]
    global genre
    genre = ', '.join(map(str, genres))
    print(movie)
    print(id)
    posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]
    showline1 = title + "\n" + str(year) + " - " + str(rating) + "\n" + str(runtime) + " minutes" + " - " + genre
    showline2 = "Director: " + directStr + "\n" + "\n" + "Writers: " + writerStr
    showline3 = "Cast: " + actors
    showline4 = "Summary: " + "\n" + str(summary)


class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    try:
        dataget()
    except:
        print('Error')
        dataget()

    posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]
    showline1 = title + "\n" + str(year) + " - " + str(rating) + "\n" + str(runtime) + " minutes" + " - " + genre
    showline2 = "Director: " + directStr + "\n" + "\n" + "Writers: " + writerStr
    showline3 = "Cast: " + actors
    showline4 = "Summary: " + "\n" + str(summary)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

    def clk(self):
        try:
            dataget()
        except:
            print('Error')
            dataget()

    def clk2(self):
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App=MyApp()
    App.run()
```

My.kv

```
<RootWidget>:
    cols: 2
    rows: 1
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 1
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        AsyncImage:
            id: poster
            source: root.posterurl
            nocache: True
    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        rows: 5
        orientation: 'vertical'
        spacing: 10
        Label:
            text: root.showline1
            markup: True
            bold: True
            size: self.texture_size
            halign: 'center'
            valign: 'middle'
            id: self.lbl
        TextInput:
            text: root.showline2
            id: self.lbl2
        TextInput:
            text: root.showline3
            id: self.lbl3
            multiline: True
        TextInput:
            text: root.showline4
            id: self.lbl4
            multiline: True
        BoxLayout:
            cols: 2
            rows: 1
            spacing: 5
            padding: 50, 10, 10, 10
            size_hint_max_y: 40
            orientation: 'horizontal'
            Button:
                text: "Good Luck!"
                font_size: 14
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 95, 30
                on_press: root.app.clk()
            Button:
                text: "Exit"
                font_size: 14
                size_hint: None, None
                size: 75, 30
                on_press: root.app.clk2()
```

solved version:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
from trakt.users import User
import random
import imdb
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty, ObjectProperty
import kivy.app
kivy.require('1.9.1')

moviesDB = imdb.IMDb()
myuser = User(str('lunedor'))
watchlist = myuser.watchlist_movies

def dataget():
    global myline
    myline = str(random.choice(watchlist))[9:1000]
    movies = moviesDB.search_movie(str(myline))
    id = movies[0].getID()
    global movie
    movie = moviesDB.get_movie(id)
    global posterurl
    posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]
    global title
    title = movie['title']
    global year
    year = movie["year"]
    global rating
    rating = movie["rating"]
    global runtime
    runtimes = movie["runtimes"]
    runtime = ' '.join(map(str, runtimes))
    global directStr
    directors = movie["directors"]
    directStr = ' '.join(map(str, directors))
    global writerStr
    writers = movie["writers"]
    writerStr = ', '.join(map(str, writers))
    global casting
    casting = movie["cast"]
    global actors
    actors = ', '.join(map(str, casting))
    global summary
    summary = movie["plot outline"]
    genres = movie["genres"]
    global genre
    genre = ', '.join(map(str, genres))
    print(movie)
    print(id)


class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    try:
        dataget()
    except:
        print('Error')
        dataget()

    posterurl = ObjectProperty()
    showline1 = StringProperty()
    showline2 = StringProperty()
    showline3 = StringProperty()
    showline4 = StringProperty()

    # make a function to be able to call it
    def update_values(self):
        self.posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]
        self.showline1 = title + "\n" + str(year) + " - " + str(rating) + "\n" + str(runtime) + " minutes" + " - " + genre
        self.showline2 = "Director: " + directStr + "\n" + "\n" + "Writers: " + writerStr
        self.showline3 = "Cast: " + actors
        self.showline4 = "Summary: " + "\n" + str(summary)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # you will need that object later so put in into variable
        self.rw = RootWidget()
        # call update function
        self.rw.update_values()
        return self.rw

    def clk(self):
        try:
            dataget()
            # after you get new values update the variables connected to widgets
            self.rw.update_values()
        except:
            print('Error')
            dataget()

    def clk2(self):
        exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    App=MyApp()
    App.run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use root or app, not both together. In your case it would be app because your functions are in App class:

```
on_press: app.clk()
```

---

Of course it won't update by itself, you update global variables but don't update local ones. Try this:

```
class RootWidget(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    try:
        dataget()
    except:
        print('Error')
        dataget()

    # make a function to be able to call it
    def update_values(self):
        self.posterurl = movie["full-size cover url"]
        self.showline1 = title + "\n" + str(year) + " - " + str(rating) + "\n" + str(runtime) + " minutes" + " - " + genre
        self.showline2 = "Director: " + directStr + "\n" + "\n" + "Writers: " + writerStr
        self.showline3 = "Cast: " + actors
        self.showline4 = "Summary: " + "\n" + str(summary)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # you will need that object later so put in into variable
        self.rw = RootWidget()
        # call update function
        self.rw.update_values()
        return self.rw

    def clk(self):
        try:
            dataget()
            # after you get new values update the variables connected to widgets
            self.rw.update_values()
        except:
            print('Error')
            dataget()
```

This should work. If it won't I'll tell you the hard way.

Comment: yes, that's right, it get rid of me from error message thanks, now click to button get new values(I can see that with print(movie & id) but still doesn't show new values of text and image.

Comment: That looked promising to me but I tried and getting error such as " AttributeError: 'RootWidget' object has no attribute 'showline4'", I tried to give showline items "StringProperty()" then app getting open as blank but stay that way after clicked button even :) I think I will get the hard way :)

Comment: @Lunedor oh, add self. to variables posterurl and showlines, look in my answer, I added it there

Comment: It worked, I just add ObjectProperty() and StringProperty() for posterurl and showlines, added sloved version to question. Tanks a lotttt, I eas trying to figure out that for two days..